# React typescript: generic useReducer dispatch type unknown when passed as a prop

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics

I currently have a custom generic useReducer where I pass the dispatch as a prop to a child component however TS is unable to infer the actions type.
I am not sure why the actions are conisderend unknown in the child element and so is the state item is an unknown

the Item each time is a different type of object that is picked up

`Type 'Dispatch<TableStateAction<myType>>' is not assignable to type 'Dispatch<TableStateAction<unknown>>'`

Reducer action

```tsx
export type TableStateAction<T> =
  | {
      type: "show_modal";
      value: { item: T; action: string; modal: true };
    }
  | {
      type: "hide_modal";
      value: { item: null; action: string; modal: false; message: string };
    }
```

parent component

```tsx
  const [state, dispatch] = useTableHeaderState<myType>();

    <td>
     <TableItemDropDown
    showModal={dispatch}
    actionType={dropdownType}
    currentItem={item}
    />
   </td>
```

Child component

```tsx
interface TableItemDropDownProps<T> {
  showModal: Dispatch<TableStateAction<T>>;
  actionType: ModalActionType[]; 
  currentItem: T;
}

 showModal({
        type: "show_modal",
        value: {
          item: currentItem,
          action: action,
          modal: true,
        },
      })
```

useReducerState

```tx
export type TableState<T> =
  | {
      modalShown: false;
      modalItem: T;
      modalAction: string;;
    }
  | {
      modalShown: true;
      modalItem: T;
      modalAction: string;
    }
  | {
      modalShown: false;
      modalItem: null;
      modalAction: string;
    };
```

UseReducer function

```tsx
export function useTableHeaderState<T>(): [
  TableState<T>,
  Dispatch<TableStateAction<T>>
] {
  return useReducer(
    (state: TableState<T>, action: TableStateAction<T>): TableState<T> => {
      switch (action.type) {
     case "show_modal":
          return {
            ...state,
            modalItem: action.value.item,
            modalAction: action.value.action,
            modalShown: action.value.modal,
          };
        case "hide_modal":
          return {
            ...state,
            modalItem: action.value.item,
            modalAction: action.value.action,
            modalShown: action.value.modal,
            errorMessage: action.value.message,
          };
```

Comment: Where & how do you use `TableItemDropDownProps`?

Comment: Based on the code that you have posted here there is no reason for `TableStateAction<T>` to be generic.  I don't think it's possible to answer this without seeing more code.  It might be that you need to give React a little hit and explicitly declare the generic type for a component instance, like `<TableSearchHeader<T>  onSorted={dispatch} onFiltered={dispatch} />`

Comment: I updated the post with the appropriate state and actions given why they need to be generic. since each time the action is fired a diffrent object is placed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution wasn't related to the reducer or the dispatch but rather I was using `React.memo()` for my child components as a result the props were lost when using a generic component. There are currently several [work arounds](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/37087)

My approach  `const MemoTest = React.memo(Test) as typeof Test;`